# Запись в бинарный файл структуры

Tags: c++, файлы, app

Доброго дня. По заданию требуется записать в бинарник несколько массивов структур. 
Как я делал: передаю массив и размер в функцию, считываю из файла первые четыре байта(int), меняю размер, так как дозаписываю. Закрываю файл, открываю вновь. Записываю поверх старого размера новый размер. Затем, вновь закрываю файл, открываю вновь с дозаписью в конец(!!!), и записываю содержимое массива. 
Как это работает: если один раз записать массив структур и считать его обратно - то все нормально. Если дозаписать ещё один массив структур..то он не дозаписывается. Отладчиком определил, что поток для записи в конец не открывается нужным образом(функция tellp() возвращает 0, то есть курсор в самом начале файла, и писать будет сверху старого содержимого). Вот функция:

```
void write_file(std::string name, bank *b, int s)
{
std::ifstream file_r(name, std::ios::binary);
int tmp_size(s);
if (file_r)
{
    int size(0);
    file_r.read((char*)&size, sizeof(int));
    s += size;
    file_r.close();
}
std::ofstream file(name, std::ios::binary);
file.write((char*)&s, sizeof s);
file.close();
file.open(name, std::ios::out | std::ios::app |  std::ios::binary);  // НЕ ДОЗАПИСЫВАЕТ
int pos = file.tellp();  // файл открывается в начале 
for (int i(0); i < tmp_size; i++)
{
    int count = b[i].name.length();
    file.write((char*)(&count), sizeof(int)); // размер строки
    file.write(b[i].name.c_str(), count); // пишем строку
    file.write((char*)&b[i].num, sizeof(int));
    file.write((char*)&b[i].code, sizeof(int));
    file.write((char*)&b[i].sum, sizeof(int));
    file.write((char*)&b[i].data, sizeof(date));
}
file.close();
}
```

Надеюсь, я нормально преподнес информацию. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Пока что я хочу обратить внимание на то, что при открытии файла при помощи `ofstream` просто в режиме `binary` (да и без него тоже) все данные, которые были в файле, будут стёрты.

Comment: Постарался отобразить всё:
https://pastebin.com/zJ3Lq0VW

Comment: Если программу запустить в первый раз - все нормально. Во второй раз она будет выводить только то. что было записано до этого.

Comment: я верю, что ваш пример можно существенно сократить (например, убрав структуры, кучу полей, ввод-вывод с экрана) - он не минимален, и читать его целиком - трата времени. Также приведённый вами код всё ещё не компилируется - он не самодостаточен.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zJ3Lq0VW
напоминаю: для получения проблемы следует запустить программу несколько раз.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто сразу откройте файл для записи  в режиме чтение-запись и без `append`:

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open(name, std::ios::binary | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::in);
```

это предотвратит truncate файла и позволит произвольно менять его содержимое.

Вы окажетесь в начале  файла 
для записи нужного размера, а затем можно переместиться в конец

```
file.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
```

Однако, если файла еще нет, то его нужно создать, поэтому проще всего добавить в начало кода (перед открытием на чтение-запись) пару строк

```
file.open ("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
file.close();
```

---

А можно не морочить никому голову и открыть файл сразу создавая его, если такого еще нет в удобном для чтения-обновления-дозаписи режиме, используя POSIX:

```
int fd = open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
FILE *f = fdopen(fd, "r+");
```

Comment: Ваше решение очень помогло. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен соответствующий флаг при открытии файла, попробуйте так:

```
std::ifstream file(name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
```